# SQL to find duplicates in a table where we have one or two extra characters

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am struggling in writing a query to find duplicate value in a column where the row 1 matches with row 2 exactly but row 2 has some more characters .

For example -:

```
             data
             1800284375KW
             1800284375
             12345RE24
             12345RE24W
```

Comment: Can you provide more context around what you’re trying to accomplish? It seems like an odd scenario.

Comment: my product team created a table and now they are trying to find data issues within the data.They want us to give them a list of records which match with each other most  part of the string but differ in 1 or 2 characters.

Comment: It might be easier to dump that data to a file and write a small program (eg in Python), since there is no easy SQL code for "differ in 1 or 2 characters".

Comment: Are the extra characters always going to be at the end of  string? Is one of the strings always going too be “correct” e.g. 12345 should match 12345ABC but 12345ABC would not match 12345DEF

Comment: Yes the extra characters are going to end of the line